# Where can I find BlackBerry's Android runtime?

Tags: android, blackberry, runtime

BlackBerry now have a [Android Runtime](https://developer.blackberry.com/android/). Cool. But I wonder if this runtime is available to be downloaded itself. I've read that only BlackBerry 10 devices comes with this runtime, and I'm researching ways to put my Android apps on older BlackBerries.
Does someone know a location to download the runtime (not simulators or tools to pack apps)?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK is not available to be downloaded because is part of the OS itself.
Anyway, also Blackberry Playbook comes with Androud Runtime.

Comment: The Android player won't run on any BlackBerry Smartphone OS prior to 10.